# How to use Symfony parameters in User Entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

This is a `Symfony 3` project.

In User entity, i need to implement the method `getRoles()`. I have a private member `$roles` that is an array and I added it into `serialize` and `unserialize` methods.

```
public function getRoles()
{
    if (count($this->roles) == 0) {
        $this->roles = { ... read from db ... };
    }
    return $this->roles;
}
```

A issue I'm facing is that in `... read from db ...` part, I have to use some parameters from `parameters.yml`. Usually, `$this->container->getParameter(...)` does the job. Unfortunately, from an entity I have no access to the container.

My question is: **How can I access parameters.yml from an Entity?**
Can I somehow inject the required parameters?

Another question is: **do I need to serialize `$roles` as well** or should they be read on every request?

--- EDIT ---

That logic seems to me correctly placed.

`getRoles()` function is supposed to get user's role to Security bundle. It accomplishes it by querying private members and ORM relations. The only problem is that I need do identify certain groups, as they don't have similar names in all deployments. Thats why I need the parameters.yml.

Here is a fragment from User entity, which implements `AdvancedUserInterface`.

```
public function getRoles() {
    $ADMIN_GRP = "ADMIN_GROUP";      // I need this from parameters.yml
    $SUPPORT_GRP = "SUPPORT_GROUP";  // I need this from parameters.yml

    $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
    foreach ($this->memberships as $m) {
         if ($m->getGroupId() == $SUPPORT_GRP) 
             array_push($roles, "ROLE_SUPPORT");

         if ($m->getGroupId()) == $ADMIN_GRP) 
             array_push($roles, "ROLE_ADMIN");
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

Comment: You should'nt put that kind of logic into entity. Use doctrine events instead.

Comment: It seems I cannot access the container from `LifecycleEventArgs` either.

Comment: I mean 'preUpdate', 'postUpdate', 'preLoad' etc...

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, I cannot help it: /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad()
     */
    public function onPostLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $container = $args->... ?
    }

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add "listeners" to the events, so use Doctrine Event Listeners for that "magic".

Comment: From what I can recall, there are discussions about removing Doctrine Events in newer major versions. You should probably have some kind of service to handle that logic

Answer (score 1):

as malcolm said, you should not be touching the EntityManager, from inside your entity, that logic is **NOT** correctly placed.

also, you should not read parameters.yml from inside your entity

(you **COULD**)

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
$value = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.yml'));
```

*but you really **SHOULDNT** use the above approach*

(you could also add constants to the user entity ...)

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding a group label to your Membership entity ? So you can do...

```
public function getRoles() {    
    $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
    foreach ($this->memberships as $m) {
         if ($m->getGroupRole() == 'ROLE_SUPPORT') 
             array_push($roles, "ROLE_SUPPORT");

         if ($m->getGroupRole()) == 'ROLE_ADMIN') 
             array_push($roles, "ROLE_ADMIN");
    }
    return $roles;
}
```